# How to do this countdown

Tags: php, time, count

I have a end date in the database

i get the current date, let's suppose is in UTC

```
class Datecalc
{

    public $year;
    public $month;
    public $day;
    public $hour;
    public $min;
    public $sec;

    function diff($start,$end = false)
    {
        if($start > $end)
        {
            $this->day = 0;
            $this->hour = "00";
            $this->min = "00";
            $this->sec = "00";
            return false;

        }
        if(!$end) { $end = time(); }
        if(!is_numeric($start) || !is_numeric($end)) { return false; }
        $start  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$start);
        $end    = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$end);
        $d_start    = new DateTime($start);
        $d_end      = new DateTime($end);
        $diff = $d_start->diff($d_end);

        $this->year    = $diff->format('%y');
        $this->month    = $diff->format('%m');
        $this->day      = $diff->format('%d');
        $this->hour     = $diff->format('%H');
        $this->min      = $diff->format('%I');
        $this->sec      = $diff->format('%S');

        return true;
    }

}
```

I use this function to calculate the difference in time, but the problem is that i cant count days to 99, and when the date is 00:00:00, the days -1, and its sets to 98 and the time 23:59:59, in this code its all good, but if the number of days gets higer than 30, its resets to 01, i think you understand what i am trying to say, please help!!

in other words i need to count the days separately, and the time needs to be binded to that days

Comment: Its always a good idea to do date calculation with timestamps, cause you got only one number to handle, and can transform the timestamp after calculating to a proper days/month/whatever string.

Comment: Convert your date to EPOC standard, do the difference, then manually convert it to month/day etc.

Comment: oh man, i am really confused about that, can you give me a little example that helps me understand?

Answer (score 1):

The method you use will never allow you to get days > 30 because any days above 30 will be converted to another month...
This might be better approach for you:
http://www.prettyscripts.com/code/php/php-date-difference-in-days 
Or
http://www.bizinfosys.com/php/date-difference.html 
(Simple google search btw...)

Comment: i have been searched for long, i have founded a script that count the days , but how can i bind the time to that days, because when the time gets 00:00:00, the days still the same

Comment: function dateDiff ($d1, $d2) {
// Return the number of days between the two dates:

  return round(abs(strtotime($d1)-strtotime($d2))/86400);                                                                                       
}  // end function dateDiff                                                                                           okay i have fount this script, but how can i bind the real time???, when the time sets to 00:00:00 will the days countdown?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be checking if $end is false before you check is $start is greater than $end.

That said, the diff method returns a DateInterval object (http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), which has a number of options, including total number of days between the dates, as well as years, months, days, etc. You probably want to be using what is already returned by the diff method, rather than the format function.

```
$diff = $d_start->diff($d_end);
echo 'Total days difference: '.$diff->days;
echo 'Year, Month, Days, time difference: '.
$diff->y.' y, '.$diff->m.' m, '.$diff->d.' d, '.$diff->h.' h, '.$diff->i.' m, '.$diff->s.' s, ';
```